# Issue with toDF, Value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have attached code snippet for error "value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD". I am using scala 2.11.8 and spark 2.0.0. 
Can you please help me to resolve this issue for API toDF()?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object HHService {
    case class Services(
    uhid:String,
    locationid:String,
    doctorid:String,
    billdate:String,
    servicename:String,
    servicequantity:String,
    starttime:String,
    endtime:String,
    servicetype:String,
    servicecategory:String,
    deptname:String
    )

    def toService = (p: Seq[String]) => Services(p(0), p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5),p(6),p(7),p(8),p(9),p(10))

    def main(args: Array[String]){
        val warehouseLocation = "file:${system:user.dir}/spark-warehouse"
        val spark = SparkSession
            .builder
            .appName(getClass.getSimpleName)
            .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
        .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate()
        val sc = spark.sparkContext 

        val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext;

        import spark.implicits._
        import sqlContext.implicits._

        val hospitalDataText = sc.textFile("D:/Books/bboks/spark/Intellipaat/Download/SparkHH/SparkHH/services.csv")
        val header = hospitalDataText.first()
        val hospitalData= hospitalDataText.filter(a => a!= header)
        //val HData = hospitalData.map(_.split(",")).map(p=>Services(p(0), p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5),p(6),p(7),p(8),p(9),p(10)))
        val HData = hospitalData.map(_.split(",")).map(toService(_))

        val hosService=HData.toDF()
    }
```

}

Answer (score 5):

1] Need to get sqlContext as below.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

This solved my issue. Earlier below code snippet is used to get sqlcontext.
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
(This way it is worked with spark-shell)

2]
case class need to be out of method. This is also mentioned in most of the blogs.

Comment: `case class need to be out of method.` this work for me

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue using notebooks in DataBricks converting my code to simple functions. Had to déclare the class out of the function and all was working well :

```
%scala

case class className(param1 : String,
                      param2 : String,
                      ...
                      lastoaram : Double)

def myFunction(params) = {
a lot of code 
...
var myVarBasedOnClasseDefinition = Seq(myVarBasedOnClasseDefinition ("init","init","init",0.0,0.0,"init",0.0))
for(iteration <- iterator) myVarBasedOnClasseDefinition = myVarBasedOnClasseDefinition ++ additionnalSequence
display(myVarBasedOnClasseDefinition.toDF())
}
```

Hope this will help as the sentence "case class need to be out of method" didn't really seemed to apply in my case in the beginning of my search has all was working fine using a procedural like code.